# tkinter в PyCharm не выводит линии

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

В python 3.10 окно работает нормально, но в пайчарме линий просто нет, только чистое окно.

```
    from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, Text, W
    import math
    from math import sqrt
    from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style
    
    
    class Example(Frame):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.initUI()
    
        def initUI(self):
            canvas = Canvas(self)
            #Canvas.create_text(500, si2, anchor=W, font="Purisa 10",text="wp")
            #Canvas.create_line(ut1, si1, ut2, si2, fill="#400040")
            dop = 9
            print('open')
            canvas.create_line(20, dop, 20, dop)
            canvas.create_line(20, dop, 20, dop, dop, 500)
            #canvas.create_line(20, 20, 20, 500)
            #canvas.create_line(20, 20, 20, 500, 500, 500)
    def print_hi(name):
        root = Tk()
        ex = Example()
        root.geometry("700x600+300+300")
        root.mainloop()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print_hi('PyCharm')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без применения методов геометрии pack, grid и place ничего на экране не появиться. Немного поправил код

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.config(bg='red')

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='green')
        self.canvas.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.canvas.create_text(100, 100, anchor='w', font='Purisa 20', text='wp')
        #self.canvas.create_line(ut1, si1, ut2, si2, fill="#400040")
        dop = 9
        print('open')
        self.canvas.create_line(20, dop, 20, dop)
        self.canvas.create_line(20, dop, 20, dop, dop, 500)
        self.canvas.create_line(20, 20, 20, 500)
        self.canvas.create_line(20, 20, 20, 500, 500, 500)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame = Example(self)
        self.frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```